# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'next' and Function missing 2 required positional arguments: 'x' and 'y'

Tags: python, linked-list

I am trying to write a program to insert a node at a specific position and the errors I am getting are,

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'next'
```

and also

```
Function missing 2 required positional arguments: 'x' and 'y'
```

Code:

```py
class SinglyLinkedListNode:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
        self.next = None


class SinglyLinkedList:
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None
        self.tail = None

    def insertnode_end(self, data):
        node = SinglyLinkedListNode(data)

        if not self.head:
            self.head = node
        else:
            self.tail.next = node

        self.tail = node

    def print_ll(self):

        temp = self.head
        while temp is not None:
            print(temp.data, end=" ")
            temp = temp.next

    def insertNode_pos(self, data, pos):
        new_node = SinglyLinkedListNode(data)
        if (pos == 0):
            new_node.next = self.head
            self.head = new_node

        temp = self.head
        while temp.next is not None:
            for _ in range(pos - 1):
                temp = temp.next
            new_node.next = temp.next
            temp.next = new_node


llist_count = int(input())
llist = SinglyLinkedList()

for _ in range(llist_count):
    llist_item = int(input())
    llist.insertnode_end(llist_item)

data = int(input())
pos = int(input())

llist.insertNode_pos(data, pos)

llist.print_ll()
```

Comment: Please provide full traceback.

Comment: Lots of errors here. Also, the `insert node at position` function is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see x and y in your code. It is helpful if you include the full traceback. It seems that your function is hitting the last node in the list, whose `next` item is None. Obviously, `None` doesn't have the `next` and `data` attributes.

Meanwhile, I modified your insertNode_pos function. One important line here is `return` if `pos == 0`. Your function doesn't need to continue in that case.

```
 def insertNode_pos(self, data, pos):
    new_node = SinglyLinkedListNode(data)
    if pos == 0:
        new_node.next = self.head
        self.head = new_node
        return

    temp = self.head
    for iter in range(pos):
        if iter == 0:
            temp = self.head
        else:
            temp = temp.next
    new_node.next = temp.next
    temp.next = new_node
```

One more note is that implementing `__str__` is a more common practice for printing content of your data:

```
def __str__(self):
    output = []
    temp = self.head
    while temp is not None:
        output.append(str(temp.data))
        temp = temp.next
    return ",".join(output)
```

Then you can simply say `print(llist)`